# Why can't I add a custom image in my navigation?

Tags: php, navigation, menus

Trying to add a navigation Home icon Failing to work.

**Here's my nav:**

```
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
        <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

I've tried adding:
`<img src="/home.png"/>` to the second line, still no success.

**I have tried:**

`<img src="http://fullpathtoimage/home.png" /><h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>`

Thanks

Comment: Show your code, pls. Where exactly did you put this `<img>`?

Comment: What did your code look like that was not working? `<img src="http://fullpathtoimage/home.png" /><h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>` Have you considered setting it as a background image, then declaring in in css?

Comment: hey user, I've done that, but I'm not really sure how to then hide the text. I only wanted an image of a house for the home section

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do - do you have a live example we could check out? Are you trying to add a home icon to replace the menu toggle H3? or is it part of your site navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

You have to search your style.css file and find

`/* Buttons */`

Under that you will find the following classes

```
.menu-toggle,
article.post-password-required input[type=submit],
.bypostauthor cite span {}

.menu-toggle,
button,
 {}

button[disabled],
input[disabled] {}

.menu-toggle:active,
.menu-toggle.toggled-on,
button:active,
 {}
```

There are 2 states of the button that you need to configure.

Hover and active.

Just change the `background-image:url('');` for each state to what image you want in the background.

Then just either negative indent the text by -9999 or delete the text from the `header.php` file as you previously stated.